# How can I loop textBox.text in Lua

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I would like to set my textBox.text equal to 1\n\2\n3\n...\n100 I searched through the docs but do not find any solution.

I tried to use table with textBox. I used textBox.text = mutable but it doesn't work :(

Any help would be appreciated, Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried anything? That doesn't look hard if you know how to use `for` loop.

Comment: I tried to use table with textBox. I used textBox.text = mutable but it doesn't work :(

Comment: `textBox.text = ('\n'):rep(99):gsub('()',tostring)`

Comment: Could you expand your code Egor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply loop for as many lines as you need:

```
function lineNumbers(num)
    local content=''
    for i=1,num-1 do 
        content = content .. i .. '\n'
    end
    return content .. num
end

textBox.text = lineNumbers(100)
```